# Does NSMutableSet's addObject method replace a duplicate or ignore insertion?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, collections

I am struggling to figure if whether adding an already existing object to a set in Cocoa actually replaces the object or simply ignores `addObject:` if there is a duplicate. I am using a custom object that is considered the same as another object if a specific field is equal.

I am overriding both `isEqual:` and `hash` methods and `containsObject:` does return `true` when I call it, but I would like to update the set with the new object and for some reason it doesn't work if I call `addObject:`.

If it does ignore it, what would be the best data structure to use in place of `NSMutableSet` in order to have the desired effect?

Comment: I'd suggest that if you have objects that passes the "is member of set" test *but* the object you are inserting is somehow different than the one that is in there, you have a very serious design problem on your hands that'll likely cause repeated maintenance issues over time.

Comment: Well as an example, I have a collection of person objects and each person object has a unique id. If, from a web service, I receive  an updated version of one of the person objects, let's say their name has been changed, it is much neater to have a single method to replace that object in the collection. I can't see how that could be a design flaw.

Comment: You should be updating the existing person object, most likely, See Core Data.   If you have two instances in memory that have the same UUID, but are not actually identical and there is no transactional layer managing the differences, then you need code to resolve that issue (i.e. you need to re-invent what Core Data can do in a relatively automated fashion).  Maybe the set is a part of that data management layer.

Comment: Using Core Data would only make sense if the data needs to be stored as opposed to working with a collection of objects in memory. Otherwise, using an entire framework to solve a very specific problem seems a little heavyhanded.

Comment: Hardly;   I've frequently used Core Data as a local in-memory cache for what is otherwise stored remotely.  It has typically resulted in far less code, a much easier to understand formal data model, and moving to a persistent cache on the local disk is pretty straightforward.   Sure, overkill for some things....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableSet`'s [`-addObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/addObject%3a) method will *not* add an object which passes the `-member:` test, as such it doesn't do anything.

If you still want to update the set with the new object regardless, you can use an `NSMutableArray`, on which you'd call [`-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABBBECB):

```
@interface NSMutableArray(JRAdditions) 
- (void)addUniqueObject:(id)object;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray(JRAdditions) 
- (void)addUniqueObject:(id)object {
    NSUInteger existingIndex = [self indexOfObject:object];
    if(existingIndex == NSNotFound) {
       [self addObject:object];
       return;
    }
    [self replaceObjectAtIndex:existingIndex withObject:object];
}
@end
```

Comment: In the end, I actually created a category on NSMutableSet that removed the member object and then added the new version. Which is pretty close to what you have above.

Answer (score 15):

[From the description](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/addObject%3a), it *ignores* if there is a duplicate.

> Adds a given object to the set, **if it is not already a member.**

You could cast the NSMutableSet to a CFMutableSet, which has methods that allows greater control on how to add objects (you want CFSetSetValue):

- [**CFSetSetValue**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableSetRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001503-CH201-F11095): The value to be set in *theSet*. If this value already exists in *theSet*, it is replaced.
- [**CFSetAddValue**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableSetRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001503-CH201-F11073): If *value* already exists in the collection, this function returns without doing anything.
- [**CFSetReplaceValue**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableSetRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001503-CH201-F11093): If this value does not already exist in *theSet*, the function does nothing.

Comment: This is the best answer because you link to the relevant documentation. :) Upvote for you!

Comment: @KennyTM Didn't know about these CF functions. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

It returns without doing anything. `NSMutableSet` is toll-free bridged to `CFMutableSet`, and from [the docs for that class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableSetRef/Reference/reference.html):

> If value already exists in the collection, this function returns
>   without doing anything.

Comment: I want to upvote this, but there's no need to drop down to `CFSet` for info--it's covered by the `NSSet` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you are missing the idea of "equality". If you need to add an object to a set because it's different, then the "is equal" operator needs to return it is different.
The ONLY valid time to replace an object in a set would be if it was entirely identical. Basic set semantics.
What you are describing is not a set if you are trying to replace an object with a different object. That is a different type of keyed collection. I would probably suggest the most logical one being a basic dictionary. key = value. So then you just assign the dictionary["objectId"] = object and it will naturally add or replace.
You need to use the right tool for the job.